# What happened to the "Publish to Gallery" option in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

The [Google Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/publishing_gallery) claims:

"With the script loaded in the script editor click Publish > Publish to Gallery in the menu bar."

After starting a new script (for spreadsheets) project, I attempted to publish to the gallery. But there is no such option:

[image]

Was it recently removed? Do I need to change a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's available on Google Apps / business accounts.  I've had to make a copy to a consumer account, then publish.