# Publish a Google script for several documents

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

I recently created a Google script for my documents but I'd like to know how to authorize **all** my documents to execute this one, not only the document that I used to develop the script...

First, Is that possible without passing on the store?

Answer (score 2):

I have great news for you! Google says they're working on that!

[image: happy friday!]

But also bad news. They've been working on it for four years now, which really means they're not working on it.

See [Issue 489](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=489), star it and wait for the announcement of project completion. He he!

---

The topic of sharing scripts among multiple documents has been covered before:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334751/how-do-i-share-a-script-i-wrote-with-my-co-workers-on-the-same-google-apps-accou?rq=1

  Libraries.
- [How to share one Google Apps script between few documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751356/how-to-share-one-google-apps-script-between-few-documents)

  Libraries.
- [What happened to the "Publish to Gallery" option in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552338/what-happened-to-the-publish-to-gallery-option-in-google-apps-script)

  The gallery was retired.
- [Google Apps Script add code to copy of a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440763/google-apps-script-add-code-to-copy-of-a-document)

  Can't do it.

**Option 1:** As those previous answers suggested (and I'm sure there are more), turn your script into a library, then in every document you want to use it you "just" need to add a script that includes the library, and functions that call the library functions.

**Option 2:** Any stand-alone script can be "tested as an add-on", which allows you to associate a script with any document. Unfortunately, just one document at a time.

**Option 3:** (Your own suggestion.) You are able to publish through the store, but limit the visibility just to yourself (any account), people with the link (any account) or your organization (domain accounts). If you're using a consumer account, you'll have to pay $5 to register as a developer for this privilege.

I'm uncertain about whether you'd need to wait for a review cycle, or if your add-on would go live immediately, or if you'd be able to skip providing help documentation, support web site, etc. - maybe someone else can weigh in on that via comment, and / or update this answer with details.

The advantage to this would be the ability to have the script in any of your documents, without adding scripts to them.

*Consumer account add-on visibility options:*

[image: screenshot]

*Corporate domain account:*

[image: screenshot]